# Android: Unable to find class inside my project

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror

Hi guys recently I noticed that sometimes my app crashes when calling/trying to initiate a class I created with the following error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com.myapp.classes.ImageSdCardCache
```

I am trying to reference/call ImageSdCardCache in an activity like this:

```
 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
    .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
    .diskCache(new ImageSdCardCache(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MyAppCache/cache"))) //the problem line
    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
    .memoryCacheExtraOptions(300,300)
    .build();
```

Here I am trying to initiate an ImageLoader but sometimes (not always) it fails with no class found exception. What am I doing wrong?

Here is ImageSdCardCache.java placed in a folder different from the folder my activity is in.

```
public class ImageSdCardCache extends BaseDiskCache {

public ImageSdCardCache(File cacheDir) {
    super(cacheDir);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure if this is the cause, but consider what mention in docs:

> **getExternalStorageDirectory()** Return the primary external storage directory. **This directory may not currently be accessible** if it has been mounted by the user on their computer, has been removed from the device, or some other problem has happened. You can determine its current state with getExternalStorageState().

Comment: A good point you made my friend. But why is the exception NoClassDefFoundError? Shouldn't it be something different?

Comment: No I use Android studio

Comment: Did you have jars files in the libs folder?